# form api ajax stops javascript loading

Tags: forms, javascript

I have set an ajax callback to a form using the form api #ajax. I also have custom jquery in a file which styles part of the page and sets click handlers. I found something funny - my custom javascript only begins working AFTER the ajax has been called on the drupal form. Before I that form api ajax is called, it doesn't work.

Why would this be?

EDIT:

I am attaching my behaviors like this:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.updateCart =  {
    'attach': function(context) {
    $(document).ready(function () {...
```

This file is being included inside of my modules hook form alter:

```
if($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
  drupal_add_js('sites/all/modules/my_subscription/js/updateCart.js');
}
```

Comment: really depends on how you are including the `custom jquery in a file` and if it is wrapped in the appropriate Drupal behavior handlers, etc.

Comment: I have added the attach code.

Comment: I don't think this is what's causing the issue, but Drupal behaviors are called when the DOM is loaded. That means you don't need that extraneous $(document).ready(function() ... call from within the attached behavior function.

Comment: @EvilE - Hey, that did it! Commenting out that line made it work! If someone could explain to me what was happening, that would be great!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it's resolved! I'll copy that comment into an answer so 1) it can help other people who get here, and 2) you can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the extraneous jQuery ready function within the behavior, it *should* still work. I guess it depends on what code resides within the javascript function and if all the jQuery selectors actually exist at that point. I would change two things to make it more "drupal"

1. Per my earlier comment, remove the jQuery ready function from within the attached behavior function
2. Attach the form javascript using the Form APIs #attached property. See [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the extra ready function fails is because you're defining a callback to the event (page ready), in the processing of a callback to that same event... eg. the callback definition is added, to an already fired event.